# How to return query from variable?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I try to search first_name, last_name and city but city is now always set whether the users want to set it with city or not. so I make query like this if request has city then filter it

```
$users = \App\User::join('profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.member_id')
            ->where(function($query) {
                $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%z%')
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%z%');
            })
            ->paginate(10);

        if ($request->has('city')) {
            $users->where('location', 'like', '%bandung%');
        }
```

but `where location like` its like never used even request has city. i've try `var_dump $users` and `count` it and end up with no city query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do little change in sequence of your lines of code:

```
$users = \App\User::join('profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.member_id')
        ->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%z%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%z%');
        });
        if ($request->has('city')) {
            $users->where('location', 'like', '%bandung%');
        }
        $users_data = $users->paginate(10);
```

The variable `$users_data` will be having proper result.

Comment: i've try exacly like your answer and paginate is never used

Comment: Does it use `city`?

Comment: sure its use city

Comment: It was not using `city` condition before even if you pass it to request. Now paginate is not being used but city is.

Comment: @Aslam, I have updated my answer. Please try it out.

Comment: Cool. Happy to help.thank you for accepting my answer and voting it up.